# Vim: Input method automatically restores when completion menu pops up

Tags: vim

I'm using Chinese Pinyin as default input method.

Every time when I use English input method to type code, it restores to Chinese input method as the completion menu pops up.

It's just like that when I switch from one mode to another mode, the input method automatically restores.

Is there any way to make vim use consistent input method?